# OpenCV imshow not responding

Tags: opencv, pycharm, operating-system, spyder, python-3.8

I have the little test.py code below

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("sample.png")
print(image) #not None

cv2.imshow("Photo", image)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm running the virtual environment on Pycharm with opencv installed.
Python version is 3.8.6

However, when I run either `python test.py` or `python3 test.py` in the Pycharm terminal, the Python launcher pops up but it's just not responding and showing any photo.

This is what it shows [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nTOi.png)

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Update: I think this is with Pycharm, I've tried again with Spyder on Anadconda, and it works fine. Windows appear.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I suspect missing or broken dependencies for the Highgui module - either GTK, QT; or even OpenCV not built with their support?

Can you include a line:

`print(cv2.getBuildInformation())`

in your code and see the GUI section of the output?

For Windows it is:

```
GUI: 
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              YES (opengl32 glu32)
    VTK support:                 NO
```

See the comments and link below: https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html

[image]

...

You say it's not None, but did you try with absolute path to the photo, is it in the same folder where PyCharm would search?

Did you try to run it from the system console shell, when you are in the directory of the image?

Edit: Also, if it seems to load the image, but doesn't display it, try to save it: cv2.imwrite("save.png", image)

Also, if you add print() after cv2.imshow() is the output displayed?

BTW, another possible source for issues could be setting of the Virtual Environment etc. when creating a new project:

[image]

Comment: did you try with absolute path to the photo, is it in the same folder where PyCharm would search?
Yes I did.

Did you try to run it from the system console shell, when you are in the directory of the image? Yes I did as well, but same issue remains.

f it seems to load the image, but doesn't display it, try to save it: cv2.imwrite("save.png", image) -> Yes, it saved the image to the new image.

if you add print() after cv2.imshow() is the output displayed? -> No, it wouldn't print. Looks like the programming is hanging while trying to launch python launcher, but it's not reponding.

Comment: If it doesn't print after imshow, then possibly cv2.imshow hangs, that makes me suspect the HighGui library, maybe some dependency missing? Qt? OpenCV has many options during building. Have you tried with other sample programs which just omit the imshow/GUI and save the output? E.g.  
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sobelX = cv2.Sobel(image, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0)
sobelY = cv2.Sobel(image, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1)
sobelX = np.uint8(np.absolute(sobelX))
sobelY = np.uint8(np.absolute(sobelY))
sobelCombined = cv2.bitwise_or(sobelX, sobelY)
cv2.line(image, (0,0), (40,40), 255, 3)

Comment: Highgui could be based on GTK (default is ON) or Qt, depending on the options during compilation: https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html

"GUI backends (highgui module) OpenCV relies on various GUI libraries for window drawing. Option  Default  Platform  Description
WITH_GTK  ON  Linux  GTK is a common toolkit in Linux and Unix-like OS-es. By default version 3 will be used if found, version 2 can be forced with the WITH_GTK_2_X option.
WITH_QT  OFF  Cross-platform  Qt is a cross-platform GUI framework. "

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by "Python launcher"? The Python executable file? If the image was successfully read and saved etc., then the Python interpreter was started and running. I think "Not responding" is typical for problems with the GUI.

Comment: Ah, now you say HighGui, I'll start looking into it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, see the Edit of the answer. What's the output of: print(cv2.getBuildInformation()) under the "GUI" section?

Comment: Here it is: 
GUI: 
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.13.2)
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    Cocoa:                       YES
    VTK support:                 NO

Comment: So now you have to check whether QT is installed for python. If it's not - install it. https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/gettingstarted.html

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/gettingstarted-linux.html

Before that you may try any sample code with QT and see if the modules are imported or the script fails due to missing libraries:
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/widgets.html

Comment: Yeah I just try the second link, did pip install pyside6, then run the program, it works fine. But somehow it just doesn't work with opencv.

Comment: I don't know is the OFF status of OpenGL critical, but anyway I'd uninstall the current installation of OpenCV since it's unusable and reinstall or rebuild with GTK backend. It is the default choice, too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm running it on the virtual environment of Pycharm, so uninstalling it shouldn't be hard, or I can just create a new project and install opencv again. Regarding the GTK backend, can please give me advice on how to rebuild it?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/

GTK is ON by default so I guess the option wil be checked by itself. There are algs GUI editors for the make file. Take care for marking GPU etc. if you need them:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cmake-gui.1.html

Comment: oh I'm using Mac Big Sur 11.1.

Comment: Well, I didn't realise that. Then maybe that's the issue, they say COCOA is the backend for MacOS:

N/A  ON  macOS  Cocoa is a framework used in macOS. See the link in the answer with the options.

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/17/install-opencv-4-on-macos/

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem still persists. So I gave it a shot with Spyder from Anaconda, magically it works with Python 3.7

Comment: OK, I see you've added you suspected PyCharm (it's known to have compatibility issues with ocv, but on my Windows it was OK), but  it didn't run on the system's console (I guessed with the same issue), which suggests it was not dependent on the IDE. You could mark the OS as well.

Comment: Somehow after couple days not using it, today it works again, like magic.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7), `waitKey` waits for a pressed key.

However, you did not specify any delay in your `waitKey`.

> delay Delay in milliseconds. 0 is the special value that means "forever".

So if you specify `waitKey(0)` the image will be displayed forever (until you press a button.)

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("sample.png")
print(image) #not None

cv2.imshow("Photo", image)

cv2.waitKey(0)  # delay 0
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks Ahx, I've tried that too, but don't think it works.

Comment: Did you try with different parameters? other than 0?

Comment: If if doesn't print after imshow (see the discussion below), it seems it doesn't reach to  waitKey. I did run the program with Pycharm community edition and it was OK. cv2.waitKey() acts like (0), it just waits until pressed, but as the question is posed the image does not appear at all? I suspect the Highgui library may have missing dependencies or something.